# Python check how many correct in list

Tags: python, list, function

I want to write a function that determines how many numbers are equal in 2 different lists, and tells whether it is a winning ticket or a losing one

```
result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Examples:

`def check_bet(bet, result):`

bet = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] – winning ticket

bet = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6] – winning ticket (2 errors)

bet = [1, 6, 2, 4, 5, 3] – losing ticket (3 errors)

Comment: Please share your code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

Juste iterate and compare, then incremente a score like this :

```
expected = [1,2,3,4,5]
input = [1,3,2,4,5]

def score(input, expected):
        score = 0
        for i in range (0,len(expected)):
                if input[i] == expected[i]:
                        score += 1
        return score
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def check_bet(bet, result):
    return len([i for i in range(len(bet)) if bet[i] == result[i]])
```

**OR**

```py
def check_bet(bet, result):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(bet)): 
        if bet[i] == result[i]: 
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
len(x for x in zip(l1, l2) if x[1]==x[2])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.